# Convert current list view filter into CAML query

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am working in sharepoint2010,

I have a custom list. `Employees`.

> http:/lists/employees/allitems.aspx

I do some filtering in the list, so the URL will automatically become like this

> http:///lists/employees/allitems.aspx?View={guid}&filterField1=fieldname&FilterValue1=123......

I want to convert this URL into CAML query, or in any other way i want to get the filtered datas as DataTable.

Is there any feature available in SharePoint SDK or any suggestion for this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

your caml query like this:

```
     <Query> <Where> 
    <Eq> <FieldRef Name='Title' /> <Value Type='Text'>123</Value> </Eq> 
    </Where> </Query>
```

and your C# code:

```
        SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
        query.Query = caml;
        SPContext.Current.List.GetItems(query).GetDataTable();
```

Comment: Hi, I cann't hard code the CAML query. Its not sure that the filter will be "Title=123". the filtering will be from the UI, that user do in the list view. I need to convert that filter into CAML query.

Answer (score 0):

After some search, i got to know it is not possible to convert into CAML automatically, so i decided to go for parsing myself.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. it is possible.!
Download [**SharePoint CAML Query Helper**](http://spcamlqueryhelper.codeplex.com/) from CodePlex.
This a very useful tool for constructing CAML query.

Now follow below steps:

1. Create a view for your list with required filters.
2. Open the SharePoint CAML Query Helper.
3. Put your credentials, open the required site.
4. It loads all the lists at right side, double click the required list.
5. Click **Open List Views**.
6. Double click the view which you have created previously.
7. Now it will display full query, select from "" to  and use it in your code (replace value with your code values).